# Laravel 4 Models and Pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using I guess what is referred to a pivot table in Laravel 4 application. I have an users table, a team table and a team_user table (the pivot)

the pivot tables structure is:

```
id (primary key)
team_id (foreign key to team table)
user_is (foreign key to user table)
created_at
updated_at
```

In my Team model I want to create a relationship for the teammates.

```
public function teammates(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('????');
}
```

How do I show the user's information (first_name, last_name) using the pivot table so I can do something like

```
@foreach($team->teammates as $teammate)
{{echo $teammate->first_name $teammate->last_name}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your keys are default (id) then:

```
public function teammates(){
    // belongsToMany (RelatedModel, table, thisModelKeyOnPivot, relatedModelKeyOnPivot)
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'team_user', 'team_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Do you know if it's also possible to access other fields from the pivot table?  For example if I wanted to show the created_at date?  I'm working on something where I have a pivot table with ids from two other tables, but also a description field, and I'm trying to show that description value... is that possible?

Comment: @DianeKaplan there's `withPivot` method that you can append to the above definition and the fields will be included in pivot data on the model.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
public function teammates(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'team_user', 'user_id', 'team_id');
}
```